# Can't understand one paragraph in Power Programming with Mathematica

Tags: pattern-matching, core-language, assignment, rule

In the chapter 7 of the *Power Programming with Mathematica*, there is a paragraph discussing the behavior of `Set-` functions: (page 205. *(pdf version p. 224)*)

However, I can't get the author's meaning. It may due to the material itself, or due to the reason that I'm not native speaker in English. I totally don't get the red line part, as well unable to see how the word "*because*" is used here, what is the logical inference here?
[image]

Also, I can't get what author mean in the blue part in next page. Need help.[image]

**Update question:**
If it would not evaluate `Part`s of the left hand side, then except for the reason that assigning to variables in a `List` was no longer possible (e.g. `{a,b,c}={1,2,3}`), is there other decided reason or critical situation that something would not work well, so we would really appreciate if such partial evaluation is enabled?

Comment: About update, if I understand your question well it seems that memoization/caching could be tricky. e.g. `temp=1; f[temp]=2; temp=3;f[temp]=4]`.

Answer (score 11):

He is simply saying that the first argument of [`Set`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Set.html) is not evaluated before `Set` creates the definition.

However, the sub-parts of the first argument are all evaluated, including the head(i.e. part 0).

Thus in

```
f[x] = y
```

`f[x]` is not evaluated in the sense that any previous definition similar to `f[z_] := z^2` will be ignored. However, `f` is evaluated and `x` is evaluated.  Furthermore, any `Hold`-attributes `f` might have will prevent evaluation as usual.

---

Through examples:

Given these definitions,

```
ClearAll[f, x, foo]

f[a_] := foo

x = 1;
```

what new definitions will the following command create?

```
f[x] = y
(* y *)
```

It will *not* assign to `foo` because `f[x]` won't evaluate.  It will also not assign to `f[x]` because `x` *will* evaluate.  It will instead assign to `f[1]`.

```
?f

Global`f

f[1]=y

f[a_]:=foo
```

However, if `f` has the `HoldAll` (or similar) attributes, `Set` will honour this before evaluating parts of its left-hand-side.

```
ClearAll[f, x, foo]
SetAttributes[f, HoldAll];

f[a_] := foo

x = 1;

f[x] = y
(* y *)

?f

Global`f

Attributes[f]={HoldAll}

f[x]=y

f[a_]:=foo
```

Comment: (Assuming the following discussion is without `Hold-` attributes.) So if the lhs of `=`(`Set`) is atomic symbol, then it is held. If the lhs of `Set` is in contrast normal equation, namely of the form `h[expr1,expr2,...]`, then `h` is evaluated, `expr1`, `expr2`, ... are also evaluated? But being that said, if there is a direct global rule defined beforehand that  can match `h[expr1,expr2,...]`, then the kernel would pretend not knowing it.

Comment: Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 7):

If `Set` would not have the `HoldFirst` attribute, it would lead to undesired behavior if variables on the left hand side have already values assigned to them. Here is an emulation of that:

```
set[a_, b_] := Set[a, b]
ClearAll[a, b, c]
set[a, 1]
set[a, 2]
a
```

> 1
>
> Set::setraw: Cannot assign to raw object 1.
>
> 2
>
> 1

If it would not evaluate `Part`s of the left hand side, then assigning to variables in a `List` was not possible (this can be considered as syntax sugar). Here I emulate what would happen if `Set` would handle `List` on its left hand side like any other head:

```
ClearAll[a, b, c, list];
set[list[a, b, c], list[1, 2, 3]];
{a, b, c}
list[a, b, c]
```

> {a, b, c}
>
> list[1, 2, 3]

Comment: Is there a typo of the result on the very last line `list[a, b, c]`? My 10.4 
 version gave me the answer `list[1,2,3]`.

Comment: @Eric Jepp. Fixed.

Comment: If it would not evaluate `Part`s of the left hand side, then except for the reason that assigning to variables in a `List` was no longer possible (e.g. `{a,b,c}={1,2,3}`), is there other decided reason or critical situation that something would not work well, so we would really appreciate if such partial evaluation is enabled?

Comment: I would sey no, there is no other reason, at least no one that comes to my mind. Of course, I don't know for sure.